# Eevee - Shader not appears in render image

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I am learning blender by myself and now so confused.
This is my viewport for render test.
[image]

This is the render image. First of all, it is not same with the camera view.
Also, the shaders just look white.
[image]
What is the problem?

Comment: Could you please post your fix as an answer and mark this as accepted afterwards? That way others can find it more easily.

Comment: Hi. Please don't add "*Solved*" or "*Fixed*"  to your question or title. Instead we encourage you to post an answer below with a short description of the solution and what steps you took to reach it. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)